# The GET method is not supported for route api/login. Supported methods: POST

Tags: php, laravel, request, postman

i made a post route in laravel but when access it i find that get request was sent
this is error `Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\Exception\MethodNotAllowedHttpException: The GET method is not supported for route api/login. Supported methods: POST`

- [image: these are post routes]
- [image: this is request that i sent from postman]

Comment: what is your base_url? does it include `/api/`

Comment: Could you provide a list of all routes via: `php artisan route:list`

Comment: are you using web.php or api.php for your routes and whar is your base_url

Comment: Probably you're passing the ``base_url`` of web endpoint and not the API endpoint!

Answer (score 1):

This happens primarily because of validation issues of API as the Laravel validator sends back to the same URL, Like in this case, it is redirecting back to the login route by the GET method so it's saying you method not allowed.

For this issue, you need to change Postman settings where you need to uncheck Automatically follow redirects to off.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

If you're making the request from a tool like Postman or curl, ensure that you include the `Accept: application/json` header in your request. This informs Laravel to respond with JSON.

Answer (score 0):

Put your login/register route outside of the middleware group.